# How can I store form data in an HTML document without using a server?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making simple HTML `form` which will allow me to display form data whenever I need, for which I need to store it in a file.

I am preferring to store it in file because after going through multiple Stack Overflow threads I have learned that `form` data can be stored via `localStorage` but if cookies are cleared I will lose it.

What format should I use to store and retrieve form data, `txt` file or `json` file?

How to do it using JavaScript?

Currently I have simple actions to store `Fname`, `Lname`. Next step would be to add category for each person *e.g.* 'Manager I', 'Manager II', and so on.

Right now I have this simple code.

```html
<h1>Hey Welcome to the Portal</h1>
<div>Enter company name here</div>
<form>
  <div>
    <p>Enter Your First Name</p>
    <input type="text">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Enter Your Last Name</p>
    <input type="text">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
<br/>
<div>Click this button to show data</div>
<button>Retrieve Data</button>
```

Comment: Users can also clear/delete localstorage.

Comment: Users can also delete files. Plus storing from a file means you can't retrieve it automatically, the user will have to manually retrieve it.

Comment: I don't get it. You want to store form data on the client? But you want to prevent users from deleting that data?

Comment: If you need to store data using a method the client has limited access to, it needs to be done server-side; there's no way around it.

Comment: Clearing cookies doesn't affect localStorage. The format of the file depends on your needs; if the data are structured and built using JavaScript, might as well use JSON. Otherwise, use something else. It's completely up to you.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I read on one of stack overflow thread that localstorage data will be deleted if user selects clear cookies and time limit everything.

Comment: There are browsers that present a "Clear all stored data" type thing, which may include cookies and localStorage. And there may be browsers that choose to implement some kind of time limit on localStorage, but that would be outside of the specifications and browser-specific.

Comment: After reading comments, I just want to clarify that I would prefer to use localstorage method but only thing is if user deletes cookies, entire data in localstorage will be lost. Whereas if its file, I can at least ask client not to delete file with name "manager-data" ..

Comment: Where is this file going to live (on the user's machine)? What is the primary purpose of storing the form data? Is this file going to be created per user? etc. etc. etc.

Comment: ok addition to the post, The app will be used in offline state. So I have to store data for infinite time. And thats I have to store it on client side.

Comment: @HereticMonkey can i create that json file into a folder when the user runs it for first time on mobile ? And if its true i think there is no case of local storage then ?

Comment: EDIT: Entire app will be handed over to client. I will have no access to it anyway except for fixing bugs*

Comment: You can [edit] your own question; no need to write “EDIT” either since the edit history is available for anyone to see.

Answer (score 0):

You could use IndexedDB https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API it is a small database that you can use to store significant amounts of structured data. But you should consider and rethink how and why you want to store user data, also keep in mind user privacy and some other details that are really important when retrieving user details from a form.

Answer (score -2):

You might be overthinking this a bit.

Instead of trying to over-complicate the architecture, you need to simplify it.

I would suggest you make yourself familiar with [Progressive Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps).

Using PWA, you can easily create a syncing mechanism that will sync your server data with your client data. Treat the server data as your actual data, and client data as less important, until it syncs.

That way, you have control over the entire application and the data. So when the client clears their data, they will need to log in again, and sync their data again. No data lost. No worries.

Even if you ask your client to not delete the data, the chances are, they might.

But, if you want to stay your current route, you can use encrypted local storage (write your own encryption), IndexedDB or SQL Lite. Though, I cannot recommend this approach.

Data is sacred, and should not be stored client side as main storage.